# Resizing KDE Application launcher widget via commad-line

Tags: command-line, kde, customization, appmenu

How can I resize the `Application launcher` widget in KDE from command-line?
I want to make it larger during startup.

[image]
OS : Kubuntu 18.04
KDE : 5.12

Comment: Please advise the distro you installed (i.e., Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.) and its version. Also please note if you are using virtualizaing, and if so, which virtual engine is used. Please click [edit] and add that information to your question; please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: What application "Application launcher" do you mean? Include an image of what you have.

Comment: And is this a bump of your previous question: [KDE “application launcher” widget default size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210876/kde-application-launcher-widget-default-size) ?